# Python extraction of variable length text from a file

Tags: python, python-3.x, text-extraction

I have a text file which has data like

```
Tweet_id:"123456789", "text":"What an episode", "truncated":"false",Tweet_id:"12345678910", "text":My number is fascinating", "truncated":false
```

I want to extract only the text field

```
Tweet_id:"123456789", **"text":"What an episode", "truncated"**:"false",Tweet_id:"12345678910", **"text":My number is fascinating", "truncated":false**
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure which part exactly You want to extract but I suggest You to use [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html).

```
>>> import re
>>> string = 'Tweet_id:"123456789","text":"What an episode","truncated":"false,Tweet_id:"12345678910","text":My number is fascinating","truncated":false'
>>> re.findall('\"text\":(.*?),', string)
['"What an episode"', 'My number is fascinating"']
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a natural application of [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html).

```
import re

text_re = re.compile("""
    "text":"            # This matches the part right before what you want.
    (?P<content>[^"]+)  # Matches the content
    "                   # Matches the close-quote after the content.
""", re.VERBOSE)

for match in text_re.finditer('Tweet_id:"123456789","text":"What an episode","truncated":"false,Tweet_id:"12345678910","text":"My number is fascinating","truncated":false"'):
    print match.group('content')
```

This will print:

```
What an episode
My number is fascinating
```

The regular expression may need to get more complicated depending on the details of how consistently the data is formatted, how double-quote characters in the content of the tweet are handled in the data, etc.